# Entity framework model first connection string how to change while moving code to server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating a MVC application. Using entity framework  Db connection  string included Appsettings.config and Entity framework connection auto generated in web.config its Working fine. After i planned to move the code to server i have server details Like

Connection string in Appsettings

```
Server Database :
 <add key="thenna" value="server=123.45.45.34;database=montage;user  id=*****;password=*******;trusted_connection=false;"/>  

 Local Database:
<add key="thenna" value="server=DESKTOP-QD6A981\SQLEXPRESS;database=tickandtie;user id=***;password=*****;trusted_connection=false;" />
```

when i which one i want i can use if server db want i was comment local db connection string code . 
web config entity framework Code :

```
<connectionStrings><add name="tickandtieEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entityframework.Tickmarks.csdl|res://*/Entityframework.Tickmarks.ssdl|res://*/Entityframework.Tickmarks.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-QD6A981\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=tickandtie;user id=sa;password=Tickmarks;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

when i move server code how can i change Web config code ? i need to use  Same code or else  i need use with  server details? how to move this code server web config after publish the application ?

Comment: Are you suppose to include the `username` and the `password` of the server database?

Comment: @jonju i  need include  server username and  server password in web config  connection string?

Comment: even you publish the project with the server connection, or you can go on the server projectForder, and edit the webConfig with new connection. PS. Never post the connection string with real password!

Comment: No what I meant was aren't your `username` and `password` supposed to be secret? You are showing it to the WORLD

Comment: @jonju    changed  server name  username and password dummy

Comment: @LucianBumb now edited and hide username and password thank you

Comment: @S.Akbari  i am using model first its possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use web.config transfor to change the connection string depending on your target environment.

Here you are a couple of links

- http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx

And here an example of the transformation xml in one of my projects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- For more information on using transformations 
     see the web.config examples at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=214134. -->
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OASIS" 
         connectionString="Data source=server\instance; Initial catalog=dbname; User Id=user;Password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
         xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"
         />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

As you can see. the transform is very similar to the original declaration, but with 2 aditional attributes (xdt:Transform and xdt:Locator) that define the transformation proccess.

Comment: i  will try this and get you back @mnieto